# why am I getting this name error form my tkinter button 'command='?

Tags: python, tkinter

im getting this name error for my button. I cant figure out why. Im using tkinter and I think Ive imported all the ne

```
#this the sound shart 


    start_game = Button (text_box,command=start_game_pressed, fg='black',text = """                                               
    丂七闩尺七
    """)

start_game.place(x=450, y=400)


def start_game_pressed (self):
    print("sus")


#subprocess.call(["afplay", "soundscrate-not-done2.wav"]) 
#text and textbox configuration 

text_box.pack(expand=True)
text_box.insert('end', titletext,start_game )
text_box.config(state = 'disabled')
text_box.config(bg='black')
text_box.config(fg='white')
text_box.place(x=150, y=125)

gui.mainloop()
```

this is the error message

```
 File "/Users/odinschaefer/Desktop/torture my/main.py", line 43, in <module>
    start_game = Button (text_box,command=start_game_pressed, fg='black',text = """                                                 
NameError: name 'start_game_pressed' is not defined
```

help pls.

Comment: `start_game_pressed` hadn't been defined yet at the time you tried to use it.  Move the function definition up above the creation of the Button.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the function before you try to reference it.

```
def start_game_pressed (self):
    print("sus")

start_game = Button (text_box,command=start_game_pressed, fg='black',text = """                                               
丂七闩尺七
""")
```

Comment: It looks like the function is inside a class, so it may be `command=self.start_game_pressed` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your function before referencing it in the button. Something like this:

```py
# Notice that here, the function is 
# defined before the button is.

def start_game_pressed(self):
    print(“sus”)
start_game = Button(text_box,command=start_game_pressed, 
    fg='black',text = "丂七闩尺七")
```